# How to add a navigationBar and show another controller by code in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Now I have two Controller, one is FirstViewController,and one is SecondViewController.

In FirstViewController

```
var secondViewController: SecondViewController!

let textView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    //textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    textView.isEditable = true
    textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    return textView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    secondViewController = SecondViewController()
    secondViewController.firstViewController = self
    setUpLayout()
    addKeyboardObserver()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

then I add a button to show secondViewController's view as a custom keyboard

```
@objc func showSecondView() {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    textView.inputView = secondViewController.view
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

then in SecondViewController, as the pic show, now I wanna add a navigation bar in SecondViewController, how?(I can do it using storyboard, but I can't do it using code).
and I wanna show the ThirdViewController when the tableView in SecondViewController(the red area) is selected, and the ThirdViewController's view will show in the red area, not the whole screen,(just like the storyboard's "show" connection) how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take navigation controller from root view controller so you can hide and show whenever you want, Another thing you can do is, take navigation view controller for particular view controller. But you can not navigate (pushing) any navigation view controller. You can only present it. Check my code below

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerWithoutNavigation: UIViewController { // This is without navigation

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    func gotoNextViewController(){
        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewControllerWithNavigation())

        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.25
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        //transition is to show like pushing, Without it it will look like presenting from bottom

        self.present(nvc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

}


class ViewControllerWithNavigation: UIViewController { // This is with navigation

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding NavigationController**

Select the viewcontroller in storyboard and goto Editor -> Embedd In -> Navigation Controller

**To show another view controller**

*Add storyboard id to Navigation Controller
[image]

*Then add this code in action

```
let storyBoard  = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard_name", bundle: nil)
let destination = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboard_id")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```